# Citations in Glossary and on first use (glossaries-extra)

Tags: citing, glossaries-extra

I'm using glossaries-extra and bib2gls.
I'm looking for a way to add a reference to my bibliography to some glossary entries.
I am already cross-referencing glossary entries so the `see` key is already used.

I found [a guide](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/?label=cites) to add citations to the normal glossaries package, which states:

> A much simpler approach can be obtained with the glossaries-extra package.

I've searched the glossaries-extra documentation extensively. However, I couldn't find any mention of how this simpler approach could look like. If possible, I'd like a solution thank doesn't require defining a custom style.

Additionally, I want the citation (saved in a custom field of the entry) to appear on the first use of
`\gls`. If possible, this should work independently of the (Abbreviation) style.

**TLDR:** What is a simple solution using glossaries-extra and bib2gls to add a citation to glossary entries and their first use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the following solution using `\glsdefpostlink` together with
`\glsxtrifwasfirstuse` to add a citation to the first use in the text.
To add the citation to the description displayed in the glossary I used `\glsdefpostdesc`. Both of these apply the change to one specific category.
The reference(s) to the bibliography are stored in the user1 field.

In my example I'm using bib2gls however, this works perfectly well without bib2gls too.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[acronym, abbreviations, record]{glossaries-extra}

\addbibresource{main.bib}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={test-gls}]

% Customize glossary style to cite on first use for c-code category
\glsdefpostlink{c-code}{%
    \glsxtrifwasfirstuse{% true case
        \glsxtrifhasfield{useri}{\glslabel}{\space%
        % \glscurrentfieldvalue needs to be expanded
        % before being passed to \cite.
            (See \expandafter\cite\expandafter{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
        {}% false glsxtrifhasfield
    }% end true glsxtrifwasfirstuse
    {}%{<false>} glsxtrifwasfirstuse
} % end glsdefpostlink

% Customize glossary display style to include citation if present
\glsdefpostdesc{c-code}{%
    \glsxtrifhasfield{useri}{\glscurrententrylabel}{\space%
    % \glscurrentfieldvalue needs to be expanded
    % before being passed to \cite.
        (See \expandafter\cite\expandafter{\glscurrentfieldvalue})}%
    {}% false glsxtrifhasfield
}% end glsdefpostdesc

\begin{document}
    First use: \gls{sample}.
    Second use \gls{sample}.
    Test without useri: \gls{no-cite}.\\
    \printunsrtglossary
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Glossary test-gls.bib:

```
@entry{sample,
    name = {Something},
    description = {No description},
    category = {c-code},
    user1 = {bib-entry}
}
@entry{no-cite,
    name = {Something2},
    description = {No description},
    category = {c-code}
}
@entry{normal,
    name = {texttt works},
    description = {No description},
}
```

Bibliography main.bib:

```
@book{bib-entry,
    author       = {Some author},
    title        = {Some title},
}
```

[image]